# Android Studio Gradle Cannot resolve symbol 'applicationVariants'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to get around an annoying issue with Gradle that does not allow libraries to have different min/target sdk's.  The solution was to add the following to build.gradle.

```
android.applicationVariants.all{ variant ->
    // This is an annoying hack to get around the fact that the Gradle plugin does not support
    // having libraries with different minSdkVersions. Play Services has a min version of 9 (Gingerbread)
    // but Android Maps Utils supports 8 (Froyo) still
    variant.processManifest.doFirst {
        File manifestFile = file("${buildDir}/exploded-bundles/ComGoogleMapsAndroidAndroidMapsUtils03.aar/AndroidManifest.xml")
        if (manifestFile.exists()) {
            println("Replacing minSdkVersion in Android Maps Utils")
            String content = manifestFile.getText('UTF-8')
            content = content.replaceAll(/minSdkVersion="8"/, 'minSdkVersion=\"9\"')
            manifestFile.write(content, 'UTF-8')
            println(content)
        }
    }
}
```

However when i do that, I get an error that applicationVariants cannot be resolved.  How do I fix this?

Comment: The IDE will give you many incorrect errors, if you're using Android Studio.  Just ignore them if it builds cleanly.  Looking at my build file, I also get that error for applicationVariants but it still builds.

Comment: Huh, you're right. Make it an answer!

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you guys add an answer? @styler1972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparrently, this is an Android Studio bug and is telling me there are errors where there's none. Building and ignoring works fine.